# Changing legend name and legend values and other things

Tags: r, charts, legend, lines

Hello this is my code:

```
datos_tem <- dbGetQuery(connection, paste("SELECT temp_int,hum_int,datetime FROM datalog_v2 WHERE host_id=69 and datetime>='2013-10-01 00:00:00' and datetime<='2013-10-01 23:59:00';", sep=""))
dbDisconnect(connection)

datos_tem$datetime <- as.POSIXct(datos_tem$datetime)
datos_tem$temp_int <- as.numeric(datos_tem$temp_int)
datos_tem$hum_int <- as.numeric(datos_tem$hum_int)


#gg <- qplot(datos_tem$datetime, datos_tem$temp_int) + geom_line()        # first line
#gg <- gg + geom_line(aes( x=datos_tem$datetime, y=datos_tem$hum_int )) # add the second line!

Molten <- melt(datos_tem, id.vars = "datetime")
print(Molten)
ggplot(Molten, aes(x = datetime, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100)) +
   xlab("Time") +
   ylab("Temperature")+ 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "#0000FF"))+
  opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white'))+
  geom_line(size=1.9)
```

And produce:

[image]

But I have tried a hundred of things to change Legend name and legend name values (temp_int and hum_int must be changed to "Temperature" and "Humidity" and variable lengend name by "Medidas").

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your use of `opts` suggests that you are using a _very_ out of date version of ggplot. You should upgrade; the answers you get to ggplot questions may not even be compatible with your version of ggplot.

Comment: Changed in my code, but the same result.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood. The version of ggplot that you are using is very, very old. You need to re-install ggplot, not simply change your code. (Although the new version includes many changes what will require alterations to your code.)

Comment: Yes I know. But I've tried the solution of the first response, but it doesnt work, and I thought it may be by use opts. Sorry

Comment: Also note that you can set the scale titles (x, y, color, fill, etc.) from just `+ labs(x = ...,y = ..., color = ...)`. To set the labels in the legend, you either need to use `scale_*` as below, or change the values in the data.

Comment: This might help (after you update ggplot2) http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/#modifying-the-text-of-legend-titles-and-labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
+ scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "#0000FF"), 
                   name="Medidas",
                   labels=c("Temperature", "Humidity"))
```